# Unable to add scrollbar events to WPF listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, events, scrollbar

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with WPF and NET 4. I am trying to capture scroll events but when I try to add them in XAML using

```
<ListBox x:Name="DefinitionListBox" Height="288" ScrollViewer ... >
```

However ScrollViewer exposes *only* properties but *no* events. I have read in one place that this may be an issue with Windows 10 (but is isn't). There are plenty of examples where scroll events are defined in the XAML file but I cannot make them appear here.

How do I attach a scroll event to a listbox?

**UPDATE**
I am seeing the same behaviour in Windows 7 so ignore the Windows 10 comment.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2012 and it looks the same. Just type in the event normally and it just works fine, e.g: `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="someHandler"`.

Comment: Thanks @KingKing. I can now confirm that I am having the same problem in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it was an Intellisense problem. If I add the XAML items manually, as suggested by @KingKong above, it all works.

```
<ListBox x:Name="DefinitionListBox" Height="288" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="someHandler"
```

Sigh.